# Azure API Time slowness/timeouts when server not under much load

Tags: performance, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service running an MVC Web API.  It connects to a DB and Redis cache.  The calls to the API are taking a massive amount of time or timing out.  I have stripped back the methods to be doing pretty much nothing.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetData()
    {
           Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "abc");
    }
```

I still have the same issue.  The webserver isn't under any pressure, nor is the DB, both below 30%.   I'm at a loss to know where to even start.

This method is called quite a lot so there may be a lot of concurrent requests. I'm running an S3 App Service plan which should more than suffice.

Any suggestions on how to trouble shoot greatly welcome?  I can only think it is down to the number of simultaneous requests.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this issue is often caused by:

```
requests taking a long time
application using high memory/CPU
application crashing due to an exception.
```

I suggest you could firstly enable diagnostics logging for your web app.
By using this way, you could find the details information about Detailed Error, Failed Request Tracing,Web Server Logging in your web application.
More details, you could refer to bellow link:
[Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log)

You could also use the Azure App Service Support Portal.
By using this way, you could troubleshoot issues related to your web app by looking at HTTP logs, event logs, process dumps, and more.

You can access all this information using our Support portal at http://.scm.azurewebsites.net/Support

More details, you could refer to below link:
[New Updates to Support Site Extension for Azure Websites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-updates-to-support-site-extension-for-azure-websites/)

Besides, you could also refer to this article:[Troubleshoot slow web app performance issues in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation)